# What should i do for accommodating large scale data storage and retrieval?

Tags: python, mysql, nosql, distributed-computing, large-data-volumes

There's two columns in the table inside mysql database. First column contains the fingerprint while the second one contains the list of documents which have that fingerprint. It's much like an inverted index built by search engines. An instance of a record inside the table is shown below;

```
34 "doc1, doc2, doc45"
```

The number of fingerprints is very large(can range up to trillions). There are basically following operations in the database: inserting/updating the record & retrieving the record accoring to the match in fingerprint. The table definition python snippet is:

```
self.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fingerprint` (fp BIGINT, documents TEXT)")
```

And the snippet for insert/update operation is:

```
if self.cursor.execute("UPDATE `fingerprint` SET documents=CONCAT(documents,%s) WHERE fp=%s",(","+newDocId, thisFP))== 0L:
                self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `fingerprint` VALUES (%s, %s)", (thisFP,newDocId))
```

The only bottleneck i have observed so far is the query time in mysql. My whole application is web based. So time is a critical factor. I have also thought of using cassandra but have less knowledge of it. Please suggest me a better way to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Get a high end database. Oracle has some offers. SQL Server also.

TRILLIONS of entries is well beyond the scope of a normal database. THis is very high end very special stuff, especially if you want decent performance. Also get the hardware for it - this means a decent mid range server, 128+gb memory for caching, and either a decent SAN or a good enough DAS setup via SAS.

Remember, TRILLIONS means:

- 1000gb used for EVERY BYTE.

If the fingerprint is stored as an int64 this is 8000gb disc space alone for this data.

Or do you try running that from a small cheap server iwth a couple of 2tb discs? Good luck.

Comment: i would love to go with free/open source solutions rather than Oracle stuffs. Is there any other way around?

Answer (score 1):

That data structure isn't a great fit for SQL - the 'correct' design in SQL would be to have a row for each fingerprint/document pair, but querying would be impossibly slow unless you add an index that would take up too much space. For what you are trying to do, SQL adds a lot of overhead to support functions you don't need while not supporting the multiple value column that you do need.

A redis cluster might be a good fit - the atomic set operations should be perfect for what you are doing, and with the right virtual memory setup and consistent hashing to distribute the fingerprints across nodes it should be able to handle the data volume. The commands would then be

```
SADD fingerprint, docid
```

to add or update the record, and

```
SMEMBERS fingerprint
```

to get all the document ids with that fingerprint.

SADD is O(1). SMEMBERS is O(n), but n is the number of documents in the set, not the number of documents/fingerprints in the system, so effectively also O(1) in this case.

The SQL insert you are currently using is O(n) with n being the very large total number of records, because the records are stored as an ordered list which must be reordered on insert rather than a hash table which is constant time for both get and set.

Comment: Redis needs to fit all the database in memory, with trillions of entries, the total ammount of memory of the server can make it unafforable. I thins that another NOSQL database can make the work better, for example Tokio Cabinet, CAssandra etc...

Comment: That was only the case for v1 - the current version can store the data on disk. You still have to be careful how you organize things for really big datasets, but that will be true for any data store.

Answer (score 0):

[Greenplum data warehouse](http://www.greenplum.com/), FOC, postgres driven, good luck ...

Comment: going for money is certainly not on my options ... i would love to bring the best out of my cheap commodity hardwares and FOSSs. Thanks for the link anyway :)